# Receiving byte array thats a pdf. Want to convert it to multipart part file so I can upload to s3. Trying to get uploadFile method to accept bytes?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

The method I am trying to refactor I would like it to accept bytes instead of multipart file.

```
public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {

    String fileUrl = "";
    try {
        File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
        String fileName = generatedFileName(multipartFile);
        fileUrl = endpointUrl + "/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;
        uploadFileTos3Bucket(fileName, file);
        file.delete();
} catch ..........
```

method to upload to S3

```
private void uploadFileTos3Bucket(String fileName, File file) {
    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file));

}

private String generatedFileName(MultipartFile multipart) {
    return new Date().getTime() + "-" + multipart.getOriginalFilename().replace(" ", "_");
}

private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
    fos.write(file.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    return convFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemIterator;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemStream;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;

...

if (MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.equals(entity.getMediaType(), true)) {
    try {
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(1000240);
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        FileItemIterator fileIterator = upload.getItemIterator(entity);
        while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream fi = fileIterator.next();
            byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(fi.openStream());
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, path, is, metadata);
            request.setMetadata(metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(request);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

So you iterate over the uploaded files and for each file (or specific file you need) you can open a stream then pass that to S3, here I used Guava to handle the stream, you can you other library you wish.